# Missing cursor in Visual Studio editor after doing a search or using a clipboard manager. Works in safe mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have an odd behavior with Visual Studio 2010 editor. Whenever I do a search (ctrl-F) or do a paste using a clipboard manager like ClipX or Ditto, the cursor is missing. I have to click with the mouse inside the editor to get the cursor.

When I do these actions with Visual Studio running in safe mode, they work fine. So I thought it might be an extension or add-on causing this. I disabled all the add-ons and extensions and ran VS with /resetsettings and /setup but I still get the issue.

Any ideas on what might be going on?

**UPDATE:**

Switched to VS2012 which doesn't have this issue. VS2012 has the same extensions

Comment: This [**idea**](http://bit.ly/12eQ2eq) comes to mind.

Comment: What OS are you running?  Which language editor (eg C# or VB)?  Does it happen in other languages?

Comment: @Sepster Windows 74 64 bit. It happens in C# and VB.

Comment: @arttronics, your lmgtfy takes you to THIS page! :)

Comment: @matrixugly, Click "Search tools" then for Time choose "Past year" to get most recent hits. e.g., July and August 2014 hits are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with different ways (depends on the cause). Try the following:

- (Windows settings issue) go to Control Panel, Ease of Access Center, Make the computer easier to see, and under Make things on the screen easier to see set the thickness of the blinking cursor to 1
- (Visual Studio issue) reset all settings in VS by Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings. Restart VS and check. If problem is still actual then start devenv /safemode in VS2010 command prompt to avoid extension loaded and check the bahavior. This should help.

BTW This issue occurred quite often during the RC period of VS.

UPD
Try removing C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions this.

Comment: 1- It's already set to 1. That's the default in Windows. 2- It works in safe mode and I already mentioned this fact.

Comment: It didn't help but I don't want to remove the extensions I use.

Answer (score 0):

After following @arttronics' advice, I have some suggestions that may help (or of course, may not!) based on a bit of Google research.

I'd try these in the following order:

1. Reduce the hardware acceleration in your video driver's settings.
2. [Disable WPF hardware acceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx) (This is meant for the purpose of debugging your WPF-based application, but have seen discussion threads suggesting that disabling this will correct problems similar to what you've described)
3. [Enable single-click URL navigation](https://superuser.com/a/484119) as per Fernando Figueiredo's answer.

Hope something here helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for: Visual Studio editor's text cursor disappears after changing focus to another app, and does not reappear.

None of the (many across web) posted solutions for the disappearing text cursor worked.  I found a solution that works for me ... goto:

Tools/Options/Environment/General/Window layout

...there are 2 radio buttons:

- Tabbed Documents
- Multiple Documents

...you must select one or the other.  I switched to 'Multiple Documents' and this solved the problem.

Side note:  this problem manifests when changing the focus to any other open window/application via Alt+Tab.  On return, Vis Studio has no text cursor visible.  Ctrl+Tab is a sorry workaround, yet effective.  But this fix is totally sat for me.