# How to open a VS2010 solution in VS2012 without migrating or changing any file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I work in a team who use Visual Studio 2010. I started using Visual Studio 2012 to work in our VS2010 solution. I understand that VS2012 can open a VS2010 solution and keep the compatibility with VS2010. However I noticed that VS2012 made changes to all the .sln, .csproj file. Plus every .datasource in the webreference folder & a few .Designer.cs files. After these changes, VS2010 can still open the solution.

However my concern is that when the other developers get the latest code, they will load a bunch of files which shouldn't be modified and they will be alarmed.

I can't go through explaining that the modified files are OK or the modifications won't hurt anything... because I am supposed to be using VS2010.

Is there a way to use Visual Studio 2012 and keep ALL the files untouched when opening for the first time? I guess using VS2012 in 100% VS2010 compatibility mode, if such thing exists.

Comment: So you are looking for a technical solutiuon to a non technical problem. What feature in visual studio 2012 are you using that is not available in 2010? Because VS2012 is making some changes to the underlying project files, I would want to get team management approval before switching software versions. IF for some reason you really need to use vs2012 work on a private copy of the project. It will require that you will need to migrate changes manually but you do have a good reason for doing this in the first place right?

Comment: Why would they be loading files which shouldn't be modified? Why would they be alarmed? And why can't you try this out yourself and find out?

Comment: I want the IDE enhancements. There are a lot of them. They have nothing to do with my code. I am also still using .NET 4.0 and not 4.5. Why do you say it's not a technical problem? The issue is very similar in IE9 where it can emulate IE8 or IE7. I want VS 2012 to emulate VS2010. Maybe there's a switch in VS2012 for this to happen. I also have a specific issue with VS2010 as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655668/missing-cursor-in-visual-studio-editor-after-doing-a-search-or-using-a-clipboard

Comment: @John Every time I commit a change, I am going to get a long list of files which were modified by VS2012 and not by my and I have to exclude them. If I add a new file, the .csproj will be modified which I have to commit but I don't want VS2012's changes to be included. They will be alarmed because the changes are not by me but by the tool I use and therefore there needs to be an explanation. There's no justification for me to use VS2012 if everyone else is using VS2010 and VS2012 is making changes which are not applicable to them. I don't understand your last question.. find out what?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you using local workspaces with VS2012? Best not to do that if you're interoperating with VS2010.

Comment: @John I am using SVN and every developer has a copy of the repository on their machine. SVN is aware of every file that gets modified and every modified file will be among the files to be committed to the repository. Files changed by VS2012 will be among them. That will be an issue because these modified files are not needed for the other developers because they are pertinent to my setup only. I don't think I can make myself any more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

With only a few exceptions projects in VS2012 are backward compatible with VS2010.

[This question has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095339/visual-studio-2012-doesnt-convert-vs2010-solution) in a bit of a different way.

Also look at the [Compatibility for VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx)  It should help you determine if changes you are making will affect your coworkers.